# Prove that the cardinality of $\Bbb N$ is less than the cardinality of $\Bbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand there are different ways of showing this. One would be to use functions and mappings and another way is to express cardinality arithmetically? But if the sets are uncountable then it is not possible to express arithmetically?

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is countable.

Comment: @dfan yeah isn't $ #N = 2^n $ ?

Comment: You want to show there exists no injection $\Bbb R\to\Bbb N$. Show first there is a bijection $\Bbb R\to \Bbb 2^{\Bbb N}$, then use Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff can you please expand on how to show there exists a bijection?

Answer (score 2):

This is my favorite proof:

**Proposition**: $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Proof: Let define the map $f: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{R}$ by the formula $f(A):= \sum_{n\in A}10^{-n}$. Note that the map is well-define since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 10^{-n}$  is absolutely convergent.

We shall show that $f$ is one-to-one. Suppose to the contrary that there exists $A, B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) $ such that $f(A)=f(B)$ but $A \not=B$. Then the set $(A\setminus B )\cup (B\setminus A)$ is non-empty. Let $n_0$ be the least element and for concreteness assume that $n_0 \in A\setminus B $. So we have

\begin{align}0=f(A)-f(B)=\sum_{n\in A}10^{-n}-\sum_{n\in B}10^{-n}=\sum_{n\in A:n<n_0}10^{-n}+10^{-n_0}+\sum_{n\in A:n>n_0}10^{-n}\\-\sum_{n\in B:n<n_0}10^{-n}-\sum_{n\in B:n>n_0}10^{-n}\\
=10^{-n_0}+\sum_{n\in A:n>n_0}-\sum_{n\in B:n>n_0}10^{-n}\\
\ge 10^{-n_0}-\sum_{n>n_0}10^{-n}\\
=10^{-n_0}-\frac{10^{-n_0}}{9}>0
\end{align}

a contradiction. Hence $f$ is an injection.

Then $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\simeq f(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$, i.e.,  $f(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$  has the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and by the Cantor's theorem  $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable. Since $f(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then this forces $\mathbb{R}$ to be uncountable and in particular greater cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$.

as was to be shown.

Edit: I've fixed some typos.

Comment: This is interesting, how did you decide on a formula for the map f(A) ?

Comment: @C.Y.Cheng : I saw it time ago.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N}) < \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) = \mathrm{card}(2^\mathbb{N}) = \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R})$.  The first two are trivial.  For the last, there are two historical proofs (due to Cantor): [the first one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof) and [the diagonal one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).  Further discussion of the cardinality of the continuum is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_real_numbers).

Comment: We know $\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N}) < \mathcal{P}$ by Cantor's theorem but how do you know $\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N}) = \mathrm{card}(2^\mathbb{N})$ ? Then how do you know $\mathrm{card}(2^\mathbb{N}) \leq \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @grayQuant: $2^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all possible assignments of "in the subset" and "not in the subset" to the elements of $\mathbb{N}$.  This is the same thing as the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$.  (I.e., $2^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow 2$.)

Comment: @grayQuant:  Have you read anything about the continuum hypothesis?  [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis ]

Comment: This answer is a bit confused - $\mathrm{card}(2^{\mathbb{N}}) = \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R})$ always.  What's _not_ necessarily true, and what's related to CH, is the statement that $\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R})=\aleph_1$, the cardinal immediately after $\aleph_0=\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at CH, it's mentioned briefly but not used in my book. Also @StevenStadnicki, how do we know this \mathrm{card}(2^{\mathbb{N}}) = \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R})  ?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki is correct.  Correcting the answer.  Recommended reading on this point:  [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_real_numbers ]